# Calling plugin function inside custom plugin for onclick event

Tags: plugins, functions, hooks, actions, events

I want `testFunction()` to call `check()` that i created in my plugin php when i click **My Button**. How do i make it work ?

```
<?php
function createButton()
{
    echo '<button onclick="testFunction()">My Button</button>';
}

function check()
{
    alert("Works");
}

function my_php_function()
{
    echo '<script>
    function testFunction() {
      check();
    }
  </script>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_php_function' );
```

Comment: You're mixing up PHP and JavaScript. `check()` either needs to be a JavaScript function in a .js file or between `<script></script>` tags, or if it needs to be a PHP function, you need to use AJAX to run the function on the server. Your code is just sample code so I can't tell what you need.

Comment: ``check()`` needs to be a PHP function. So i need to use AJAX, how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is the solution. For more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Separate_JavaScript_File

Answer (score 0):

I could not stand by and see that mangled code. Here is what I think you meant to do.

```
<?php
function createButton()
{
    echo '<button onclick="testFunction()">My Button</button>';
}

function my_php_function()
{
    echo '<script>
    function check()
    {
        alert("Works");
    }
    function testFunction() {
      check();
    }
  </script>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_php_function' );
```

Comment: I specifically wanted  to do it without echo.